# Angulajs dynamic form data with dynamic layout

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, forms

I have a form which is built as a directive. I am providing the data for layout in my controller.
**MyController.js**

```
[{
"type":"selectbox",
"name":"name_one",
"label":"Name One"
}]
```

This data is then passed to my form_directive which then loads the template.

Then I am getting the actual data to be populated from an ajax call, inside **MyController.js**
eg:

```
$http.get('url/location').success(function(data) {

    }).error(function(data) {

    });
```

The data that is coming from the ajax will be like this:

```
[{
"id":"090986735",
"name":"option_1"
},{
"id":"78645679",
"name":"option_2"
}]
```

Now my question is how to bind this data to the selectbox?

Please note that there will be many such controls. But I have shown only one select box

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the model of select.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select - the example with colors should be useful for you.